# Specify Go build flag "-H=windowsgui" in code comment

Tags: windows, go

I am creating a desktop Windows application in Go. Currently I use this line to install it:

`go install -ldflags -H=windowsgui`

I want users to be able to just say

`go get github.com/my/app`

and automatically have the `windowsgui` flag specified for building. Is it possible to add the flag as a code comment, like `#cgo` comments. Or would I have to provide a `make` file in the project directory like in the old days of Go? Or is it not possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad news, you can't.

Semi-good news, you can tell your users to use `go get -ldflags "-H windowsgui" github.com/my/app` on Windows.